# UISearch Bar prompt overlaps with status bar while presenting as UISearchController

Tags: swift, xcode8, ios10, uisearchcontroller

Code for Presenting SearchController:

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:viewcontroller) 
storageLocation.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
searchController.searchBar.prompt = "Some random text"
self.definesPresentationContext = true 
searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = .white 
self.present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your storageLocation spacing to the top is -20. When you set your constraints in the storyboard, don't be alarmed by the padding at the top (even thou you set 0 spacing), that's for the status bar.

Options:

- **Set storageLocation top spacing to 0 instead of -20**
- **Hide the status bar**

**To hide the status bar, include this at the bottom of your VC:**

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
```

In your info.plist set a key "UIRequiresFullScreen" with YES.

In your project settings -> target -> general (where you set your app name, bundle identifier, signings etc), at Deployment Info, make sure "Hide status bar is selected"